# Why isn't java8 in yum?

Tags: linux, centos, java, yum

I have multiple dedicated boxes that execute java applications. I used to install java 7 from yum. I decided to upgrade to java 8. I have installed java 8 manually on a lot of boxes. I am curious to know why yum has never had java 8 added in. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle Java8 runtime and SDK contain many [encumbered components](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/sun-bulk-java-open-sourced-003), and can only be redistributed as approved by Oracle.

Oracle claims they are working with the OpenJDK community to re-implement many of these features, but that has been slow going. The general release for the OpenJDK 8 was just in [March](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) (3/18/2014) so its brand new. Most software that goes into repositories has been well tested and is considered mature and stable enough for inclusion in production environments.

It also appears that the OpenJDK community has not yet provided a [prebuilt installation package](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) for Deb or Yum repositories yet.

Comment: +1 even though it's not what I wanted to hear. ;)

Comment: Also, note that the Java8 platform is considered both immature, and most everyone is still on 7. 8 really hasn't taken off the way previous versions have, and I believe that legal ambiguity is part of the issue, considering some of the disaster that was the Oracle v Google case.